# Whey Intent.ACTION_VIEW start a google search in Meizu phone

Tags: android, android-intent

I've tried to find a solution but nothing help me. My problem is that with the code that you can see below I can open a url in a browser in all the phones unless in Meizu. When I run the code in Meizu phone the browser open a google search with the string that I put in mUser.getTwitterUrl() that, obviusly, is a full url like www.twitter.com

Anyone know what could be the problem?

Than in advance

```
 Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http:/"+ mUser.getTwitterUrl()));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Meizu m2 note mobile. I think the problem is there is only one slash (/) after http, Thats why the browser open a google search. Put two slashes and try. I guess mUser.getTwitterUrl() returns "twitter.com/[twitter-username]"

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://"+ mUser.getTwitterUrl()));
    startActivity(browserIntent);
```